# Python: apply regex on dataframe with datetime as a column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe (`df`)as follows

```
Index     Month     Time       Text_1          Text_2                 Text_3
  0      02/2019   19:44:33   aadd@34:9984    (none)\       62fa6297-f5f5-4c47-8236-4a85cad5e601
                                             STBROWN2-M-26YQ
  1      02/2019   19:30:22   58:EF:68:14    (none)\        f933fb2a-4dde-a547-80ca-3b9e6cd29a6d
                                             STBROWN2-M-26YQ
```

I have written a simple regex as follows

```
def clean(text):
text = text.lower()
text_clean = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', text)
return text_clean
```

Then I apply the above on the `df`

```
df.apply(lambda x : clean(x))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'", 'occurred at index Application')
```

It could be because of `Month` and `Time` column as they are `datetime` object.

My question is: How to apply a regex while ignoring the datetimes?

Comment: Dint work the above one. `TypeError: ('expected string or bytes-like object', 'occurred at index Application')`

Answer (score 2):

Use filter to select columns starting with Text

```
def clean(text):
    text = text.str.lower()
    text_clean = text.str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]', ' ', regex = True)
    return text_clean
df.assign(**df.filter(like = 'Text').apply(clean))
```

Comment: This solution is not working per say. Even if you apply the `clean` on the sample `df` as I shared, it would not do the needful.

Comment: @pythondumb, I have used your code with modifications so that it does not throw Attributeerror. If you want the code to perform differently, you need to provide expected output.

Comment: Will try to repost this with more enriched `df` values.

Answer (score 1):

In your data I think all data are strings, but if want exclude datetimes columns use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
def clean(text):
    return text.str.lower().str.replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '')

#filter only object columns
mask = df.dtypes == 'object'
#filter Text columns if possible
#mask = df.columns.startswith('Text')

df.loc[:, mask] = df.loc[:, mask].apply(clean)
```